# Asp.net - Could not load type Index from assembly App_Web_xxx

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm moving an asp.net site from iis6 to iis7 and I get this error. I've searched many results from google, but it didn't help me.

This line at the top of Index.aspx

`<%@ page language="C#" autoeventwireup="true" inherits="Index, App_Web_0nrkgffq" %>`

causes the error:

> Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Index' from assembly
>   'App_Web_0nrkgffq, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.

It weird because "App_Web_0nrkgffq.dll" exists in the bin folder.

But why do I get this error?

I tried

```
<compilation debug="false" batch="false">
```

But it didn't work. Thanks